# ¿Por qué MainActivity nunca se entera que mi variable fue alterada en un thread Java?

Tags: java, hilos

**Hola, muchachos!** Cada vez entiendo un poquito mejor cómo funciona el tema de los hilos (threads) en Java. Sin embargo sigo teniendo problemas. Ojalá puedan echarme una mano con esto que comento a continuación.

Pongo aquí minimizado mi código. No quiero poner el código entero de las 2 clases que menciono, porque estoy seguro que les dará flojera leerlo, y porque me parece que no hace falta ponerlo aquí para entender mi problema.

En los comentarios hallados dentro de este código, explico todo, incluyendo mi duda.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static int MI_VARIABLE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // A esta altura, el log indica que la variable MI_VARIABLE es igual a 0 (cero). Todo bien aquí.
        Log.println(Log.INFO, "infor", "MI_VARIABLE: "+MI_VARIABLE);

        // Instancio e inicio un primer hilo llamado "hilo1" de una clase llamada "MiClase". La clase "MiClase" importa MI_VARIABLE así: import static com.example.miproyecto.MainActivity.MI_VARIABLE, y luego asigna el valor correspondiente a MI_VARIABLE (digamos 7). Todo bien hasta aquí.
        List params1 = new ArrayList();
        MiClase hilo1 = new MiClase(params1);
        hilo1.setName("Hilo1");
        hilo1.start();

        // Instancio e inicio un segundo hilo llamado "hilo2" de la misma clase "MiClase". Gracias al parámetro que le paso al constructor de "MiClase", este hilo2 sólo se ejecuta hasta que termine/muera el hilo1; por lo cual, cuando por fin se ejecuta el hilo2, MI_VARIABLE ya es mayor a 0 (cero). Todo bien hasta aquí.
        List params2 = new ArrayList();
        params2.add(hilo1);
        MiClase hilo2 = new MiClase(params2);
        hilo2.setName("Hilo2");
        hilo2.start();

        // El problema está aquí: la condición del WHILE siempre se cumple, por lo cual la consola imprime indefinidamente: "MI_VARIABLE es igual a 0". ¿Por qué pasa esto si casi inmediatamente después de iniciada la app, MI_VARIABLE ya es mayor a 0? ¿Por qué el WHILE nunca se entera de que esto es así? ¿Qué puedo hacer para que el MainActivity.java haga algo en caso que MI_VARIABLE siga o no siga siendo igual a 0?
        while(MI_VARIABLE==0) {
            Log.println(Log.INFO, "infor", "MI_VARIABLE es igual a 0");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDICIÓN (2020-04-07)**
Aquí pongo (muy resumido y legible) el código de MiClase:

```
import static com.example.miproyecto.MainActivity.MI_VARIABLE

public class MiClase {

    public MiClase(List params) {

        // Creo que esto no tiene ninguna relevancia por igual lo dejo. En esta clase estoy haciendo una petición a una BBDD usando PHP (todo esto mediante Volley)
        Response.Listener<String> respuesta = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONObject objetoRespuesta = new JSONObject(response);
                    String  errores       = objetoRespuesta.getString("errores");
                    boolean estatus       = objetoRespuesta.getBoolean("estatus");
                    int     numtotalitems = objetoRespuesta.getInt("numtotalitems");

                    if (errores.length() == 0) {
                        if (estatus == true) {

                            // Si PHP devuelve el integer que estoy esperando, entonces lo asignamos a MI_VARIABLE
                            if (peticion.equals("recuperarDatosParaMiVariable")) {
                                MI_VARIABLE = numtotalitems;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(JSONException e) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(contexto);
                    alerta.setMessage("Algo falló: "+e.getMessage()).setNegativeButton("Aceptar", null).create().show();
                }
            }
        };

        DataBase peticionDataBase = new DataBase(peticion, pathWebservicePHP, respuesta);
        RequestQueue cola = Volley.newRequestQueue(contexto);
        cola.add(peticionDataBase);
    }
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Comparte el código de la clase `MiClase`.

Comment: Te falta poner el código donde estas modificando el valor de `MI_VARIABLE`.

Comment: @E.Betanzos, acabo de agregar el código de MiClase, como lo digo arriba, está muy resumido y sólo pongo la estructura super-esencial. Creo que no hay nada raro, simplemente asigno valor a MI_VARIABLE. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Estás seguro que en algún momento se ejecuta esta línea `MI_VARIABLE = numtotalitems`? Porque tienen que cumplirse varias condiciones para que se modifique el valor de la variable.

Comment: @E.Betanzos Absolutamente seguro! He impreso mil veces en la consola el valor que tiene MI_VARIABLE justo después que le asigno el valor en MiClase, y siempre me devuelve 3 (que es el valor que espero).

Answer (score 1):

Intenté con la librería volley y me pasaba lo mismo, la solucción fue meter el while dentro de una tarea asíncrona, asi quedaría

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    static int MI_VARIABLE ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MI_VARIABLE = 0;

        MiClase miClase = new MiClase(this);

        new asyn().execute();
    }

}

class asyn extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        while(MainActivity.MI_VARIABLE == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("MI_VARIABLE es igual a 0");
        }
            System.out.println("MI_VARIABLE es igual a " + MainActivity.MI_VARIABLE);

        return null;
    }

}

class MiClase{

    MiClase(final Context context) {

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        public void onResponse(JSONObject object) {

                    if (object.length()>0)
                    {
                        try {
                            MI_VARIABLE = object.getInt("v");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Ocurrió un error \n" +  error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    queue.add(request);

    }


}
```

Comment: Ya había leído por ahí que podía hacer esto que comentas, pero lo desestimé porque pensaba que la solución constaba de algo infinitamente más sencillo, no sé, como poner un flag o algo. Pero en vista que nada me ha funcionado, creo que finalmente voy a ceder y a ir por la solución que propones: trabajaré los hilos usando AsyncTask, y creo que me será hasta más fácil que como lo estaba haciendo antes, ya que el AsyncTask te provee un método llamado onPostExecute(), que te permite ejecutar algo sólo después de terminada tu tarea inicial, que es justo lo que estoy buscando. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en el tema pero cuando creas el objeto se crea una nueva instancia de MI_VARIABLE para alcanzar esa variable debes referirte al objeto primero, puedes crear mejor una variable global

class Global {

```
 static int MI_VARIABLE ;
```

}

para asignar un valor desde cualquier parte lo arías así Global.Mi_VARIABLE = tu_valor

Comment: `MI_VARIABLE` es un atributo de clase y no de instancia, por estar declarada como `static`. Por tal motivo no importa si modificas su valor a través de un objeto o de la clase ya que siempre estarás modificando el atributo de la clase y no el de un objeto en particular.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección tienes toda la razón

Answer (score 0):

Revisa este código ahí está funcionando, puedes también esperar a que termine un hilo con el metodo join()

[image: MainActivity]

[image: Thread]

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega el código como texto y no como imagen

Comment: @BetaM estaría genial que ruckzake te hiciera caso! Pero si no alcanzo su edición, al rato hago la prueba con el código que sugiere!